# How do you unit test a firebase function wrapped with express?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

With firebase functions, you can utilize express to achieve nice functionality, like middleware etc. I have used [this example](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/authorized-https-endpoint/functions/index.js) to get inspiration of how to write https firebase functions, powered by express.

However, my issue is that [the official firebase documentation on how to do unit testing](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/unit-testing), does not include a https-express example.

So my question is how to **unit test** the following function (typescript)?:

```
// omitted init. of functions
import * as express from 'express';

const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});
const app = express();
app.use(cors);

// The function to test
app.get('helloWorld, (req, res) => {
   res.send('hello world');
   return 'success';
});

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Comment: You want to do online tests or offline tests?

Comment: I think offline is preferred.

Answer (score 10):

This works with Jest

```js
import supertest from 'supertest'
import test from 'firebase-functions-test'
import sinon from 'sinon'
import admin from 'firebase-admin'

let undertest, adminInitStub, request
const functionsTest = test()

beforeAll(() => {
  adminInitStub = sinon.stub(admin, 'initializeApp')
  undertest = require('../index')
  // inject with the exports.app methode from the index.js
  request = supertest(undertest.app)
})

afterAll(() => {
  adminInitStub.restore()
  functionsTest.cleanup()
})

it('get app', async () => {
  let actual = await request.get('/')
  let { ok, status, body } = actual
  expect(ok).toBe(true)
  expect(status).toBeGreaterThanOrEqual(200)
  expect(body).toBeDefined()
})
```

Comment: What is this `exports.app` method you're referring to? This isn't normally found in firebase functions index files.

Comment: it's an exported function in the index file. For example 'exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app)' in the index file wiil be in the test file 'request = supertest(undertest.api)'. So every exported function can be tested with 'request = supertest(undertest.function_name)'

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`supertest`](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest) paired with the [guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/unit-testing#testing_http_functions) from Firebase. Below is a very basic example of testing your app, however, you can make it more complex/better by integrating `mocha`.

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'
import * as testFn from 'firebase-functions-test'
import * as sinon from 'sinon'
import * as request from 'supertest'
const test = testFn()
import * as myFunctions from './get-tested' // relative path to functions code
const adminInitStub = sinon.stub(admin, 'initializeApp')

request(myFunctions.app)
  .get('/helloWorld')
  .expect('hello world')
  .expect(200)
  .end((err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      throw err
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Would something like `mock-express` work for you? It should allow you to test paths without actually forcing you to make the express server.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mock-express

Answer (score 0):

For local & no-network unit tests, you could refactor the `app.get("helloWorld", ...)` callback into a separate function and call it with mock objects.

A general approach would be something like this:

main.js:

```
// in the Firebase code:
export function helloWorld(req, res) { res.send(200); }
app.get('helloWorld', helloWorld);
```

main.spec.js: using jasmine & sinon

```
// in the test:
import { helloWorld } from './main.js';
import sinon from 'sinon';
const reqMock = {};
const resMock = { send: sinon.spy() }; 

it('always responds with 200', (done) => {
    helloWorld(reqMock, resMock);
    expect(resMock.send.callCount).toBe(1);
    expect(resMock.send).toHaveBeenCalledWith(200);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Testing is about building up confidence or trust.

I would start by Unit Testing the function in FireBase. Without more requirements defined, I would follow the documentation.  Once those Unit Tests pass you can consider what type of testing you want at the Express level. Keeping in mind that you have already tested the function, the only thing to test at the Express level is if the mapping is correct.  A few tests at that level should be sufficient to ensure that the mappings have not become "stale" as a result of some set of changes.

If you want to test the Express level and above without having to involve the DB, then you would look at a mocking framework to act like the database for you.

Hope this helps you think about what tests you need.

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten this to work using [firebase-functions-test](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-functions-test) and [node-mocks-http](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-mocks-http).

I have this utility class FunctionCaller.js :

```js
    'use strict';
    
    var httpMocks       = require('node-mocks-http');
    var eventEmitter    = require('events').EventEmitter;
    
    const FunctionCaller = class {
    
      constructor(aYourFunctionsIndex) {
        this.functions_index = aYourFunctionsIndex;
      }
    
      async postFunction(aFunctionName,aBody,aHeaders,aCookies) {
    
        let url = (aFunctionName[0]=='/') ? aFunctionName : `/${aFunctionName}`;
        let options = {
          method: 'POST',
          url: url,
          body: aBody
        };
        if (aHeaders)
          options.headers = aHeaders;
    
        if (aCookies) {
          options.cookies = {};
          for (let k in aCookies) {
            let v = aCookies[k];
            if (typeof(v)=='string') {
              options.cookies[k] = {value: v};
            } else if (typeof(v)=='object') {
              options.cookies[k] = v;
            }
          }
        }
    
        var request = httpMocks.createRequest(options);
        var response = httpMocks.createResponse({eventEmitter: eventEmitter});
    
    
        var me = this;
        await new Promise(function(resolve){
          response.on('end', resolve);
          if (me.functions_index[aFunctionName])
            me.functions_index[aFunctionName](request, response);
          else
            me.functions_index.app(request, response);
        });
        return response;
      }
    
      async postObject(aFunctionName,aBody,aHeaders,aCookies) {
        let response = await this.postFunction(aFunctionName,aBody,aHeaders,aCookies);
        return JSON.parse(response._getData());
      }
    
      async getFunction(aFunctionName,aParams,aHeaders,aCookies) {
        let url = (aFunctionName[0]=='/') ? aFunctionName : `/${aFunctionName}`;
        let options = {
          method: 'GET',
          url: url,
          query: aParams   // guessing here
        };
        if (aHeaders)
          options.headers = aHeaders;
    
        if (aCookies) {
          options.cookies = {};
          for (let k in aCookies) {
            let v = aCookies[k];
            if (typeof(v)=='string') {
              options.cookies[k] = {value: v};
            } else if (typeof(v)=='object') {
              options.cookies[k] = v;
            }
          }
        }
    
        var request = httpMocks.createRequest(options);
        var response = httpMocks.createResponse({eventEmitter: eventEmitter});
    
        var me = this;
        await new Promise(function(resolve){
          response.on('end', resolve);
          if (me.functions_index[aFunctionName])
            me.functions_index[aFunctionName](request, response);
          else
            me.functions_index.app(request, response);
        });
        return response;
      }
    
      async getObject(aFunctionName,aParams,aHeaders,aCookies) {
        let response = await this.getFunction(aFunctionName,aParams,aHeaders,aCookies);
        return JSON.parse(response._getData());
      }
    
    };
    
    module.exports = FunctionCaller;
```

and my app is mounted as app :

```js
exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(expressApp);
```

and my firebase.json contains :

```js
"rewrites": [
    :
    :
    :
    {
    "source": "/path/to/function", "function": "app"
    }
]
```

In my test file at the top I do :

```js
const FunctionCaller = require('../FunctionCaller');
let fire_functions = require('../index');
const fnCaller = new FunctionCaller(fire_functions);
```

and then in the test I do :

```js
let response = await fnCaller.postFunction('/path/to/function',anObject);
```

and it calls my function with anObject as request.body and returns the response object.

I'm using node 8 on Firebase to get async/await etc.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'pipesCount' of undefined`

Answer (score -2):

You can use [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) application for unit test.
Enter following url with your project name

https://us-central1-your-project.cloudfunctions.net/hello

```
app.get('/hello/',(req, res) => {
   res.send('hello world');
   return 'success';
});
```

Comment: Hi Sharat, thanks for your answer. True that I can test with postman, but the answer is specifically asking for unit-testing.