# How to unit test express http cloud function with multiple endpoints that post, put, delete to firestore?

Tags: firebase, unit-testing, express, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Does anyone know how to write unit tests for express http cloud functions such as the one below?

I have been looking all over for examples, but can't find anything on how to write tests for http cloud functions with multiple REST endpoints (get, post, delete, etc.) that read and write to firebase.

This is one endpoint from my http function.

```
export const api = functions.https.onRequest(app);

  app.post('/items', async (request, response) => {
    try {

      if (!request.headers.authorization) {
        response.status(401).send('unauthorized to create widget')
      }

      const { title, priority, completed} = request.body;
      const data = {
        title,
        date
      }

      const itemReference = await db.collection('items').add(data);
      const item = await itemReference.get();

      response.json({
        id: itemReference.id,
        data: item.data()
      })
      .status(201);

    } catch (error) {
      response.status(500).send(error);
    }
  });
```

This is where I am in my attempt, but I need to call the individual CRUD operations on the 'api' function

```
describe ('create', () => {
  test('creates item', () => {
    const req = {
      item: {
        id: "7Cje99bbij6LInn7d4Mo",
        data: {
            title: "Title 1",
            date: 1604678856456
        }
      }
    };

    const res = {
      send: (payload: any) => {
        expect(payload).toBe({
          id: req.item.id,
          data: {
              title: req.item.data.title,
              date: req.item.data.date
          }
        })
      }
    };
    api(req as any, res as any);
  });
});
```

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49352060/how-do-you-unit-test-a-firebase-function-wrapped-with-express

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using a library like [supertest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/supertest) to create faked requests:

```
const supertest = require("supertest");

supertest(api).post("/items")
  .send({item: {id: "abc", data: {title: "Title 1", date: Date.now()}}})
  .expect(200);
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I got these two test working

it ('Creates item', () => {
  supertest(api).post('/items')
    .send({
      item: {
        id: "abc",
        data: {
            title: "Test",
            date: 1604678856456
        }
      }
    })
    .expect({
      item: {
        id: "abc",
        data: {
            title: "Test",
            date: 1604678856456
        }
      }
    });
});

it ('Gets item', () => {
  supertest(api).get('/items/:id')
    .send({
      item: {
        id: "abc",
      }
    })
    .expect(200);
});

Comment: I assume this would not work when dealing with functions.config() or a local emulator suite. I’m trying to wrap my head around how it all works, but I’ll try to use supertest.

Comment: I can't get this to work with POST. It looks like the JSON body parser is not applied on the receiver, so the function doesn't have req.body.